# carousel one by one using Typescript(Angular8)

Tags: jquery, css, angular, typescript, carousel

I found a solution in this link [carousel on by one](https://www.bootply.com/94444#) but I am not able to work with jquery code even if I've JQuery installed in my project example: `const next = jQuery(this).next();`

I need to convert the JQuery code in the link to the jQuery library of Angular or do the same using Typescript but at which method of the lifecycle hooks in angular should I add it (OnInit, AfterViewInit,...)

```
$('.carousel .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  if (next.next().length>0) {
    next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
  else {
    $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
```

thank you

```
 <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-1" *ngIf="val">
                <span class="dot">
                  <button type="button" (click)="openModal1()" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-xl "><i
                      class="fa fa-history "></i></button>
                  <label class="carousel-label"> Modal 1</label>

                </span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-1" *ngIf="val === 'label 1'">
                <span class="dot">
                  <button type="button" (click)="openModalL1()" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-xl "><i
                      class="fa fa-history "></i></button>
                  <label class="carousel-label"> Modal L1</label>

                </span>
              </div>
               <div class="col-md-1" *ngIf="val === 'label 1'">
                <span class="dot">
                  <button type="button" (click)="openModalL1()" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-xl "><i
                      class="fa fa-history "></i></button>
                  <label class="carousel-label"> Modal L1</label>

                </span>
              </div>
               <div class="col-md-1">
                <span class="dot">
                  <button type="button" (click)="openModal()" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-xl "><i
                      class="fa fa-history "></i></button>
                  <label class="carousel-label"> Modal</label>

                </span>
              </div>
               <div class="col-md-1">
                <span class="dot">
                  <button type="button" (click)="openModal()" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-xl "><i
                      class="fa fa-history "></i></button>
                  <label class="carousel-label"> Modal</label>

                </span>
              </div>
               <div class="col-md-1">
                <span class="dot">
                  <button type="button" (click)="openModal()" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-xl "><i
                      class="fa fa-history "></i></button>
                  <label class="carousel-label"> Modal</label>

                </span>
              </div>
               <div class="col-md-1">
                <span class="dot">
                  <button type="button" (click)="openModal()" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-xl "><i
                      class="fa fa-history "></i></button>
                  <label class="carousel-label"> Modal</label>

                </span>
              </div>
               <div class="col-md-1">
                <span class="dot">
                  <button type="button" (click)="openModal()" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-xl "><i
                      class="fa fa-history "></i></button>
                  <label class="carousel-label"> Modal</label>

                </span>
              </div> <div class="col-md-1" *ngIf="number === 3">
                <span class="dot">
                  <button type="button" (click)="openModalN3()" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-xl "><i
                      class="fa fa-history "></i></button>
                  <label class="carousel-label"> Modal N3</label>

                </span>
              </div>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a structural directive in angular for carousels. Carusels are actually a typical example for them. There are many hits in web, try this one for example:

https://netbasal.com/understanding-angular-structural-directives-659acd0f67e

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in my case I do not have a list of images or items. I have divs using HTML in one row (col-md-3) and some  divs have condition to not be show [*ngIf]

Comment: updated! u'll mind that there no rule to have which div will be show.

So I want to show one by one ( but 3 active div) as link above

Comment: Ok I still have trouble do understand want exactly want to achieve, but jquery needs a rule for selecting the carousel items. You could select `col-md-1` or you might want to add another classifier. Does this link help you? http://roufid.com/use-jquery-with-angular/